# How to activate docker 1.12 in terminal without Moby the whale app on Mac

Tags: macos, docker, terminal

I should run Moby the whale app first to be able to use the latest version of Docker (1.12.0) in my terminal. Otherwise, I get an error:

> Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?

But how can I activate Docker in my terminal without launch Moby the whale app (or probably by launching this app from console)? Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is to use `docker-machine` inside VirtualBox: https://docs.docker.com/machine/

Once installed, you first start the Docker machine instance:

```
$ docker-machine start
```

Set the required environment variables for Docker to use:

```
$ eval `docker-machine env`
```

And then run Docker:

```
$ docker info
```

Comment: Good idea, thanks! As I understand, Moby the whale app run via socket by default if DOCKER_* environment variables isn't configured... Could I run this socket from the terminal instead of running app?

Comment: If I understand correctly, the socket is created by the application, so I don't think that will work. However you can run any application from the shell by using `open -a <app-name>`. Maybe that will help you.